# PHP if array key has any value then previous all value+1

Tags: php

```
$a = array(1,0,0,1,2,0,0,6);
```

In above array i need to add +1 to all previous key value if key value is not null.

```
[0]=>1 => +1 = 2 => +1 = 3 => +1 = 4
[1]=>0 => +1 = 1 => +1 = 2 => +1 = 3
[2]=>0 => +1 = 1 => +1 = 2 => +1 = 3
[3]=>1  ( here 3rd key have value so now all previous value +1 ) +1 = 2 => +1 = 3
[4]=> 2 ( again 4th key have value so now all previous value +1 ) +1 = 3
[5] => 0 => +1 = 1
[6] => 0 => +1 = 1
[7] => 6 ( again 7th key have value so now all previous value +1 )
```

Please help me on this logic.

Comment: you have numeric keys, this makes no sense at all.

Comment: Yes true , please be more elaborate

Comment: Maybe you want to remove items where the value equals to `0` ?

Answer (score 0):

here is the logic

```
 $a = array(1,0,0,1,2,0,0,6);
 $b = [];
 foreach( $a as $key => $value){
   array_push($b , $key);
   if($value > 0 AND $key>0 ){
     for( $i = 0 ; $i < count($b)-1 ; $i++ ){
        ++$a[$b[$i]];
     }
   }
 }
print_r($a);
```

Hope this help.